# How to fit every elements in every device size while retaining their placements

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am coding a front end ui with react next js and tailwind css
I set a mobile size and code the ui but in smaller devices, the elements placement are not consistent like original anymore. A lot of elements will have their own fixed size. I tried using percentage width and viewport width on these elements but no luck. In smaller devices, i want to scale each element down to fit in the current device size perfectly. In bigger devices, i want to scale up. I also tried using scale on body tag but no luck. I have an example website that behaves like that. Please help me out

[Example Website](https://wiki.hoyolab.com/m/hsr/home)
View it in mobile responsive mode and try adjusting the viewport

This is an example of an element

```
 <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-10 mt-10">
    {/* Characters */}
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <div className="rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-100 w-[2.75rem] h-[2.75rem]">
        <img src={`/assets/menu/${gameName}/${menu.characters.image}`} alt='menu' className="w-[35px] h-[35px]" />
      </div>
      <p className="text-blue-100 font-semibold mt-1">{menu.characters.text}</p>
    </div>
    {/* Weapons */}
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <div className="rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-100 w-[2.75rem] h-[2.75rem]">
        <img src={`/assets/menu/${gameName}/${menu.weapons.image}`} alt='menu' className="w-[35px] h-[35px]" />
      </div>
      <p className="text-blue-100 font-semibold mt-1">{menu.weapons.text}</p>
    </div>
    {/* Gears */}
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <div className="rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-100 w-[2.75rem] h-[2.75rem]">
        <img src={`/assets/menu/${gameName}/${menu.gears.image}`} alt='menu' className="w-[35px] h-[35px]" />
      </div>
      <p className="text-blue-100 font-semibold mt-1">{menu.gears.text}</p>
    </div>
    {/* Map */}
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <div className="rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-100 w-[2.75rem] h-[2.75rem]">
        <img src={`/assets/menu/${gameName}/${menu.map.image}`} alt='menu' className="w-[35px] h-[35px]" />
      </div>
      <p className="text-blue-100 font-semibold mt-1">{menu.map.text}</p>
    </div>
    {/* Books */}
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <div className="rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-100 w-[2.75rem] h-[2.75rem]">
        <img src={`/assets/menu/${gameName}/${menu.readable.image}`} alt='menu' className="w-[35px] h-[35px]" />
      </div>
      <p className="text-blue-100 font-semibold mt-1">{menu.readable.text}</p>
    </div>
    {/* Beings */}
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <div className="rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-100 w-[2.75rem] h-[2.75rem]">
        <img src={`/assets/menu/${gameName}/${menu.beings.image}`} alt='menu' className="w-[35px] h-[35px]" />
      </div>
      <p className="text-blue-100 font-semibold mt-1">{menu.beings.text}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you'll need to use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, a so-called "responsive" website, right? To accomplish that there are a _lot_ of things to explain and no answer would "do it justice". Media queries. Grids. Viewports. Font sizes. Interaction changes. You question is _waaaay_ to broad and you provide no code or indication you tried something and got stuck. If you want a responsive website but not spend that cumbersome time learning how to do it, you can always hire people. Or ask one of those new fangled chatty things to provide you with a bog-standard boilerplate. Otherwise, you will also have to do effort.

Comment: I tried using aspect ratio and it worked for some parts....The problem is the element sizes, they have fixed width and height and it's not ideal to make breakpoints for every single one. These element shoulds retain their size but smaller scale automatically.

Comment: Your question is much too broad as said already, I suggest you concentrate on tailwind CSS (reactjs and next.js tags are meaningless for your question, and you should add tailwind's one). Tailwind has class variants which work with media queries, to help build responsive websites. If you haven't looked at that, try it. You should edit the question with a sample of your code that illustrates your problem and describe what is wrong compared to what you expected

Comment: I edited the question and added some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

When I tried applying viewport width to elements, I am using like this

```
<div className="rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-100 w-[10vw] h-[10vh]">
```

I thought this is correct considering width should be given with vw and height should be given with vh. But it's not the case.

I used this and it worked without having the need to write media queries

```
<div className="rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-100 w-[10vw] h-[10vw]">
```